# Populate a form selection field in Laravel 4 from Database with conditions?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Using Laravel 4 and PHP I am able to query the database and populate an HTML selection box.

the magic happend with `User::find(1)->lists('username', 'user_id')`

And here is my code for the selection field.

```
<?php
echo Form::label("username", "Username", array('class' => 'col-lg-12 control-label')); }}
echo Form::select(
    'user',
    User::find(1)->lists('username', 'user_id'),
    Input::get('user'),
    array(
        "placeholder" => "US",
        'class' => 'form-control'
    )
)
?>
```

I need to modify this to only populate the Form selection with Users who's `status` is not set to `0`.

I think this is probably a simple fix but I have not found the solution yet>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen `lists()` applied to a model instance before -- I'd assume that only returns one record?

I'd try

```
// warning: untested code...
...
DB::table('user')->where('status','<>',0)->lists('username','user_id'),
...
```

I'd also move that to the controller (`$userList = DB::table('user')...`) and pass that variable to the view.  Making a database call within the view seems like suboptimal MVC.

Answer (score 4):

This should also work:

```
User::where('status', '!=', '0')->lists('username', 'user_id')
```

But as J.T. Grimes mentions, you should move this code in to a method in your Users controller, or better yet your User model in a method called getActiveUsersList():

```
public function getActiveUsersList()
{
    return $this->where('status', '!=', '0')->lists('username', 'user_id');
}
```

Don't forget to type hint your user model in your controllers __construct() method.

```
protected $user;

public function __construct(User $user)
{
    $this->user = $user;
}
```

and assign it to a variable in your controller using:

```
$activeUsersList = $this->user->getActiveUsersList();
```

which you can then pass to the view using:

```
return View::make('users', compact('activeUsersList'))
```